# Access one specific element of NSMutableDictionary getting null values in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have an `NSMutableDictionary` that loads data from a certain source.

- He is loading fine and while debugging i am sure he is loading and that in the end he has the exact number of elements. I also can see the elements as they should while debugging.
- I just want to get the value of the the row having the key `value = 3` .

I tried `NSString * myString = [myMutabDict objectForKey:@"3"]`, considering that the value is in string ,and i followed it with the debugger, and i am sure that my `NSDictionary` has elements in it , and i can see them while debugging, and i can see the `key 3` , but i still get null as an `output` …

What am i missing?

Comment: Are you sure the key is an `NSString` and not an `NSNumber`?

Comment: @rmaddy the key maybe a number..if so what should i change?

Comment: Use `[myMutableDict objectForKey:@3];`

Comment: You're a life savor @rmaddy please post it as answer ! i searched the whole internet for this small thing and i couldn't find it..post it so future developers will take advantage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure you see a value with a key of `3` and you can't load it using the key `@"3"` then it is possible that the key is a number. Use:

```
NSString *myString = [myMutableDict objectForKey:@3];
```

or modern syntax:

```
NSString *myString = myMutableDict[@3];
```

Comment: @Daij-Djan if i'm not mistaking, we're here to learn…if we knew every little thing in the whole world we wouldn't ask…sorry if i disturbed you with my eager to learn

Comment: @Daij-Djan Other than not showing the log output of the dictionary, this was actually a good question. It was clear and it showed some effort. This question is quite far from the worst ever.

Comment: @rmaddy you're right and I deleted the comment. i dont think it showed any effort but still -- nice catch :)